# Не перерисовываются компоненты в контейнере

Tags: reactjs, redux

Есть такой контейнер:

```
class OrderContainer extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    let { dispatch } = this.props;
    this.basketActions = bindActionCreators(basketActions, dispatch);

    this.deleteItemHandler = this.deleteItemHandler.bind(this);
    this.incrementCountHandler = this.incrementCountHandler.bind(this);
    this.decrementCountHandler = this.decrementCountHandler.bind(this);
}

deleteItemHandler(key) {
    this.basketActions.deleteItem(key);
}

incrementCountHandler(key) {
    this.basketActions.incrementItemCount(key);
}

decrementCountHandler(key) {
    this.basketActions.decrementItemCount(key);
}

getCount() {
    let counter = 0;
    this.props.basket.forEach(function(item) {
        counter += item.price * item.counter;
    });
    return counter;
}

render() {
    let order = [];
    var byKey = this.props.basket.slice(0);
    byKey.sort(function(a,b) {
        return a.key - b.key;
    });
    byKey.forEach(function(item) {
        console.log('PUSH', item);
        order.push(
            <Item
                item={item}
                deleteItemHandler={this.deleteItemHandler}
                incrementCountHandler={this.incrementCountHandler}
                decrementCountHandler={this.decrementCountHandler}
            />
        );
    }, this);

    return (
        <div className="banner_block">
            <Slider/>
            <div className="container">
                <h1 className="order-title">Ваш заказ:</h1>
                { this.props.basket.length != 0 ?
                    <table className="table order-table">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th></th>
                            <th>Наименование</th>
                            <th>Цена</th>
                            <th>Количество</th>
                            <th>Стоимость</th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        {order}
                        <tr>
                            <th>Сумма заказа: {this.getCount()} Р</th>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    :
                    <h1 className="order-title">Ваша корзина пуста</h1>
                }
                <form role="form">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-md-6">
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label>Телефон</label>
                                <input className="form-control" placeholder="Телефон"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-md-6">
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label>Адрес</label>
                                <input className="form-control" placeholder="Адрес"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><div className="row">
                        <div className="col-md-6">
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label>Имя</label>
                                <input className="form-control" placeholder="Имя"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-md-6">
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label>Комментарий</label>
                                <input className="form-control" placeholder="Комментарий"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success">Оформить заказ</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
}

function mapStateToProps (state) {
    return {
        basket: state.basket
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(OrderContainer);
```

И компонент:

```
class ItemComponent extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.deleteItemHandler = this.deleteItemHandler.bind(this);
    this.incrementCountHandler = this.incrementCountHandler.bind(this);
    this.decrementCountHandler = this.decrementCountHandler.bind(this);
}

deleteItemHandler() {
    this.props.deleteItemHandler(this.props.item.key);
}

incrementCountHandler(event) {
    this.props.incrementCountHandler(this.props.item.key);
}

decrementCountHandler(event) {
    this.props.decrementCountHandler(this.props.item.key);
}

render() {
    console.log('Item: ', this.props.item);
    return(
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img className={this.props.item["pic-s"] + " order-pic"} title=""/>
            </td>
            <td>{this.props.item.name}</td>
            <td>{this.props.item.price}</td>
            <td>
                <div className="input-group">
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" value={this.props.item.counter}/>
                    <div className="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger" onClick={this.decrementCountHandler}>-</button>
                        <button type="button" className="btn btn-success" onClick={this.incrementCountHandler}>+</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>{this.props.item.counter * this.props.item.price}</td>
            <td>
                <div className="buy_block" onClick={this.deleteItemHandler}>
                    Удалить
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    );
}
}

function mapStateToProps (state) {
    return {
        // basket: state.basket
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ItemComponent);
```

Если я в компоненте кликаю по кнопке с плюсом (вызываю метод `incrementCountHandler`). То в `Store` у объекта, который я передал в компоненту, изменяется `counter (this.props.item.counter)`. В контейнере перед `order.push` в цикле я вижу, что данные обновились и в компоненты передаются уже измененные данные. Но они не отображаются. То же и с `decrementCountHandler`.

Почему такое может быть?

Comment: Что такое basketActions?

Comment: данные в redux меняются? как редьюсер работает у вас?

Comment: Да, данные меняются. Counter инкриминируется. В цикле вывожу в консоль результат. А компоненты с учётом их не меняются.